# Phonegap Hide Childbrowser window plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I would like to send a URL to the Childbrowser window. But keep it hidden off the page all together, what changes would I need to make to have that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Although tempted I'll refrain from asking WHY?!? But the lack of usefulness... Anyway as it is you can't. You'd probably have to customize ChildBrowser's code to *not* show the webview, but I kind of doubt it'd load anything.

I am not proficient/interested in Objective-C so can't help further. But if you just need to load a page invisibly, why not do a JSONP call?

**EDIT:**

I had a look at the iOS source of ChildBrowser and there's a line, `webview.hidden=NO;` that could be changed to ...`YES`. But then you'd have to add some code to provide for showing the webview later.

Comment: The why is because I need to login into a website because the data I need uses some type of javascript authentication which can't get sort from a Jquery post. 

In the end I posted a field into a hidden Iframe and got the data way. I also looked into the web view.hidden=yes but all it does is hide the load page not the view from sliding up.

I sort of solved it another way .